# Redirecting after login?

Tags: login, forms

I'm using the following to let the user login:

```
       <form name='loginform' id='loginform' action='<?php echo get_settings('siteurl')?>/wp-login.php' method='post'>
                <label>User:</label><br />
                <input type='text' name='log' id='user_login' class='input' tabindex='20' /><input type='submit' name='wp-submit' id='wp-submit' value='Login' tabindex='23' /><br />
                <label>Pass:</label><br />
                <input type='password' name='pwd' id='user_pass' class='input' tabindex='21' />
                <span id="forgotText"><a href="<?php echo get_settings('siteurl')?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword"><?php _e('Forgot')?>?</a></span><br />
                <?php //echo "<input name='rememberme' type='hidden' id='rememberme' value='forever' />";?>
                <?php echo wp_register('',''); ?>
                <input type='hidden' name='redirect_to' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>' />
            </form>
            <?php
            global $opt_jfb_hide_button;
            if( !get_option($opt_jfb_hide_button) )
            {
                jfb_output_facebook_btn();
                //jfb_output_facebook_init(); This is output in wp_footer as of 1.5.4
                jfb_output_facebook_callback();
            }
?>
```

But it stays in the same page, how can I redirect the user to the home page?

Comment: Consider checking out [Peter's login redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) for custom login redirection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess here, and maybe someone more versed can back me up or set me straight

But here:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])?>'
```

Is the redirect value....  It is redirecting to the original url, wherever the user came from

If you swap that out for your home url with something like:

```
<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>
```

I would think that would do it

Comment: That's practically what i was about to post in my own answer, so i've +1'ed you instead. :)

Comment: Thanks for that!  Good to know.... must be good coffee this morning!

Comment: There is nothing like a good morning coffee. +1 for the coffee and good job on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin way to do this is use Login with Ajax. I think you can specify different URLs for different user levels after logging and registration actions.